# Optimizing non-repeatable patterns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

While looking for a pattern to use for a background I found [this pattern](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41629841/Photos/StackExchange/testbackground.jpg).

I'm currently using it for my website background.

The problem is that pattern isn't repeatable.

I have it set as the background for my body so if I use this css I get very obvious seams where each new picture begins.

```
body {
    background:url(../images/testbackground.jpg) repeat;
}
```

I already know I can fix this by rotating/flipping the photo into a much larger photo. I've already done that [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41629841/Photos/StackExchange/testbackground2.jpg). And it works perfectly, it is repeatable and it looks good on the site (You know, except for the mirroring on the seams, but that's negligible)

The problem is that I'm big into optimizing load speeds for people who have slower internet connections, so having a background that's four times the size it should be doesn't sit well with me.

Is there a way I can rotate/flip the photo using code? I'd rather not have to use a complicated jQuery/javascript script but realistically I know I'll have to.

Does anyone know of a script that does this?

Here is a reference for how it needs to be rotated:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution that flips and rotates. but i made your background repeatable :)

I just cut off the offending pixels from the right, so the background is now a bit smaller

[image: repeatable bg]

But since you are into optimization: the picture repeats in itself already! So you can further crop it to a much smaller size and still have almost the same background:

[image: the smaller bg with same effect]

Comment: I'm out now, I'll test it when I get back

Comment: Okay, here's what I have. Neither of those backgrounds are repeatable. There is sort of a darkness gradient that goes across them, so when the picture repeats the seam is very noticeable. The idea to optimize by making it smaller is valid, however, I still have to make it larger using flipping, but it won't be as large as doing that with the full-sized image. However, the smaller the image, the more it will mirror and not look random like it is supposed to. So I need to find the right ratio between appearance and speed.

Comment: Ok, i did not realize the gradient thing. well... it was a try. if i was you, I would create a background as png with a transparent color and do the gradient then via css or so.